# Dados da view estão sumindo em um determinado tempo

Tags: php, mvc, composer, view, slim

É o seguinte, pelo que eu percebi todo o projeto segue o Padrão MVC.
Só que estou com um grande problema. A *view* de pedidos existe um *refresh* simples de 30 segundos, buscando por novos pedidos. Até ai tudo bem!
O problema acontece todos os dias às 21:00, se por ventura houver um novo pedido de clientes a *view* não puxa esses dados do banco para *printar* na tela.

Pra melhorar o entendimento, os clientes usam um aplicativo *Android* para realizarem seus pedidos. Todos os pedidos que surgirem nos horários de *(00:00 até as 20:59)*, os dados são mostrado na tela, porém passou disso nada é mostrado.

Quem puder me ajudar ficarei muito grato...

---

[image: Tela em branco pois passou das 21:00h o sistema limpa a tela e nao mostra mais nada]

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

class PedidosDao extends Dao {

static public function getPedidosPorPeriodo($data1, $data2) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cpedido where ped_status != 'PEDIDO RECUSADO' and ped_dataHora between ? and ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $data1);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(2, $data2);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getPedidosPorCliente($cli_codigo) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cpedido where ped_status != 'PEDIDO RECUSADO' and cli_codigo = ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $cli_codigo);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getStatusPedido($ped_chave) {
    try {
        $sql = "select ped_status from cpedido where ped_chave = ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $ped_chave);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getCPedido($ped_chave) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from cpedido where ped_chave = ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $ped_chave);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getAllPedidos($status) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from cpedido where ped_status = ? AND DATE_FORMAT(ped_dataHora, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() ";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $status);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getItemPedido($pedchave, $prdcodigo) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from dpedido where pedchave = ? and prdcodigo = ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $pedchave);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(2, $prdcodigo);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getProdutoPedido($pedchave) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from dpedido where pedchave = ? and tipo ='PRODUTO' order by prdcodigo asc";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $pedchave);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getAdicionalPedido($pedchave) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from dpedido where pedchave = ? and tipo ='ADICIONAL'";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $pedchave);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getItemsPedido($pedchave) {
    try {
        $sql = "select * from dpedido where pedchave = ?";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $pedchave);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

static public function getProdutosMaisVendidos($data1, $data2) {
    try {
        $sql = "select sum(i.quantidade) as qtd, 
                i.prdcodigo as cod, 
                pr.prd_descricao as descr
                from cpedido p 
                inner join dpedido i on p.ped_chave = i.pedchave
                inner join produtos pr on pr.prd_codigo = i.prdcodigo
                where p.ped_status !=  'PEDIDO RECUSADO' and p.ped_dataHora between ? and ? group by i.prdcodigo order by qtd desc";
        $statement_sql = Conexao::getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(1, $data1);
        $statement_sql->bindValue(2, $data2);
        $statement_sql->execute();
        return $statement_sql->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (\PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Os pedidos chegam a ser cadastrados?

Comment: Sim, os registros são gravados no banco. Mas a view não resgata os dados. Pelo que eu entendi o desenvolvedor criou uma lógica para limpar a tela em um determinado horário e só mostrar os registros no dia seguinte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### O Problema

O que está ocorrendo é um problema com o fuso horário. Como no Brasil estamos no fuso horário `-03:00`, podemos fazer um cálculo simples, já que o servidor — normalmente — trabalha com fuso horário `00:00`.

Isso causa uma diferença de *03* horas entre você se o servidor. Caso o acesso fosse feito de Portugal, a diferença seria de 01:00 hora, ou seja, pedidos a partir das 23:00 horas, não iriam aparecer.

```
21:00 + 03:00 = 00:00 do dia seguinte
└─┬─┘  └──┬──┘  └─┬─┘
  │       │       └─────── Horário no servidor
  │       └─────────────── Diferença de horário entre você e o servidor
  └─────────────────────── Horário local
```

Caso não tenha ficado claro, você pode criar um arquivo *PHP* no seu servidor e testar com o código abaixo.

```
<?php

/* Exibe a data do servidor */
echo date("c");

/* Altera o fuso horário do servidor */
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");

/* Quebra de linha e exibe a data com o fuso horário definido */
echo PHP_EOL;
echo date("c");
```

#### Solução

Uma das formas de corrigir esse problema é setando o fuso horário no banco de dados e no *PHP*.

No banco de dados, basta executar a *query* abaixo:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-3:00';
```

Já no *PHP*, basta adicionar o código abaixo:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Sao_Paulo");
```

[**Lista de Fusos Horários Suportados**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Valdeir. realmente funcionou. porém não setei como America/Sao_Paulo pois já estava setado assim. então alterei para (America/Manaus) ai os pedidos chegaram tranquilo. o problema que tenho agora é que. claro os pedidos estão vindo com os horários errados.
Ou seja uma hora de diferença! Mas eu vou ver o que faço.

Comment: @danieellz Se você executou o código acima no MySQL, pode ser isso. Como o fuso horário de Manaus são -4:00, então você pode executar `SET GLOBAL time_zone = '-4:00';`.